# How to make Eclipse Compiler copy existing class files to the target dir?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to make Eclipse copy all the files (except .java) from the source directory to the output directory? I have some class-files under my sources, but they are filtered out. The setting "Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building -> Filtered Resources" doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I came out with a solution: add additional Builder to the Eclipse project. It's an Ant script:

```
<project name="example" default="copy_resources" basedir=".">
    <target name="copy_resources" depends="" >
        <copy todir="bin" overwrite="false">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

However I have to manually trigger the "Build Project" command in order to Ant script be executed. When I do "Clean" it is not executed...

Comment: How come you have .class file in your source directory? This looks pretty ugly...

Comment: Please check this question for the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468607/how-to-make-javac-copy-existing-class-files-to-the-target-dir

Answer (score 2):

You need to have class directories in a different directory than your source, I usually put them in a directory called "lib" (not just class directories but jars as well).

Once you have the classes in a different directory:

> Right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
>   tab > Add Class Folder button > Select the directory > OK > OK

When you build your project the class directories should be included.

Comment: It is different. ".class" files I have in my source are resources which I need to have at that place.

Comment: Please check my another question for the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468607/how-to-make-javac-copy-existing-class-files-to-the-target-dir

Comment: Why do you have to have them in the source directory? If you use the exact same package structure then it makes no difference where you place the class files (If you add them to the build path that is)

Comment: I access resources at runtime using getClass().getResource() of a class placed in the same package. This approach doesn't require absolute paths and works both from IDE and from JAR.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this?

Comment: Because resources are accessed using relative path via the helper class, they can be easily moved together with the helper class, it works both for running the program from IDE and JAR, it's not error-prone.

Comment: No, I meant to ask why are you accessing class files at runtime as resources?

Comment: I have multiple libraries and I need to load only one of them at run-time, depending on the OS. I cannot put them as JAR files in my JAR. So I extracted them and put into source folder like resources. At run-time I add the URL of the required library to the class path.

Comment: Yeah, as I thought, there's a better way to do that (in my opinion) and it's called "class folders". It's exactly like using jars but in their extracted way (so that you can include them in your jar). This can be done both with eclipse and ant (as you mentioned you want) and then there's no need to do any extra work at runtime, you just use the classes you need.

Comment: I have multiple variants of same library (for different OSs). I cannot load them all together because they have same class and package names.

Comment: There are plenty of methods to do exactly this. Have you searched on the subject before you decided to take this approach? I highly recommend you to stop with your current approach and consider others, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915315/how-can-i-package-a-java-desktop-application

Comment: Of course I did :-) Thank you for your advice, but I don't see any disadvantages which would be relevant for my situation. Probably I didn't explain my situation well to you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `.class` files are artifacts from something else, either checked in, or created by an external process. In either case, Eclipse appears to be blissfully unaware of them (from your description).

You can try the following: add a new builder to your project. Select "Ant" and choose the `build.xml` at the root of your workspace (or whatever location you decided - you need to make this file). The ant script will run whenever your project is rebuilt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="copy">
  <target name="copy">
    <mkdir dir="someplace"/>
      <copy todir="someplace">
        <fileset dir="source">
          <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
      </copy>       
   </target>
</project>
```

You just need to fixup the source and destination of the files.

Comment: You got the problem correctly. I posted same solution one minute before you :-) Unfortunately I have to manually trigger the "Build Project" operation even if "Build automatically is enabled.